# Access main viewmodel's child vm

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a menu bar, with a div that I only want visible, if the user is authenticated. My javascript files has this code:

```
var UserViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.Name = ko.observable("");
    self.IsAuthenticated = ko.observable(false);

    self.SignOut = function () {
        var uri = '/api/User/Logout'
        $.getJSON({ url: uri, contentType: "application/json" })
            .done(function () {
                window.location.href = "/Pages/Index";
            });

    }

}


$(document).ready(function () {

    var vm = {
        loginVm : new LoginViewModel(),
        registerVm: new RegisterViewModel(),
        userVm: new UserViewModel()
    }


    var uri = '/api/User/Get'
    $.getJSON({ url: uri, contentType: "application/json" })
        .done(function (data) {
            vm.userVm.Name(data.Name);
            vm.userVm.IsAuthenticated(data.IsAuthenticated);
        });

    ko.applyBindings(vm, $('#LayoutSection')[0]);
    GetTimezones();
});
```

So, when the screen loads, it does a call to "/api/User/Get" and gets a user object, and then populates a view model with the Name and if the user is authenticated.

That view model, although with two other view models, is assigned to a main view model.

In my html, I try to data bind to that view model's 'IsAuthenticated' property to make the visibility.

```
data-bind="visible: userVm.IsAuthenticated"
```

But it can't seem to see userVm.IsAuthenticated.

How can I access that property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the problem is that at the point of your data-bind, you're in a different binding context. It's hard to tell though, without seeing more of your view (HTML).

You can use `$parent`, `$parents` or `$root` to walk the binding context tree. In your case, from any binding context, you can use `$root` to refer to `vm`. You would thus write:

```
data-bind="visible: $root.userVm.IsAuthenticated"
```